# Populate fields with SQL data on selection of JQuery autocomplete item

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, razor

I have an input form with last name, first name, and email. Rather than typing in the text boxes and clicking submit to create a record in DB-2, I want to search another existing database DB-1 with jQuery autocomplete and pull the user info from a table there. So when I click the autocomplete choice it should populate the three text boxes with their info, so that when I click submit it will create a record in DB-2 with data that is consistent with what is in DB-1.

Currently I have the input fields and submit button working for DB-2. I can manually type in last name, first name, and email and when I click submit the record gets added to DB-2. I also have autocomplete working so that I can scan a table in DB-1 and select a record. However I'm not sure how to populate those input fields. I think it must be something like this [jQuery autocomplete documentation example](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote). However, don't just need what I selected I need the several other columns associated with that selection. Here is the code I have now.

```
<form method="post">      
        @Html.TextBox("lastName", Request.Form["lastName"], new { maxlength = 50 })
        @Html.TextBox("firstName", Request.Form["firstName"], new { maxlength = 50 })
        @Html.TextBox("email", Request.Form["email"], new { maxlength = 50 })
        <p><input type="submit" name="btnSubmit" value="Assign Reader" /></p>
</form>
```

Here is my widget code:

```
<div class="ui-widget">
        <input id="fullname" name="fullname" placeholder="Search by Name" size="50">
</div>

   List<string> LastNames = new List<string>();
    foreach (var item in db1.Query("SELECT * FROM myTableInDB1; "))
    {
        var LName = item.LastName;
        var FName = item.FirstName;
        var eMail= item.email;           
        var FullName = LName + ", " + FName;
        FullNames.Add(FullName);
    }    
<script>
    $(function () {
        function log( message ) {

<<note: this is where the jQuery example has the selection posted 
 to a log. I can do that but just with the FullName data. I'm not 
 sure what happens to the other data in the above foreach.>>

        }
        var FullNames = @Html.Raw(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert
                      .SerializeObject(FullNames.ToArray()));
        $("#fullname").autocomplete({
            source: FullNames,

<<note: I also added this bit in to test that my selection 
 was getting posted to the log window>>

            select: function( event, ui ) {
            log( ui.item ?
              ui.item.value : this.value );
        }
        });
    });
</script>
```

So again, how can I use the autocomplete to search out the record I need then once it is selected collect all those variable values for LName, FName, and eMail when I am only pulling (FullName) into my autocomplete array.

Do I need to use the selection to do another query of the db-1 then add those returns to the text boxes? I could do this if I had the id of the selection from the autocomplete but I don't know how to get that.

What would be even better is if there is a way to pull those values in during that foreach process.

I am about ready to just copy some code that returns query results in gridview then I could populate the text fields using a gridview selection. However, it would look cleaner on the page if this autocomplete could be wired up some way. Thank you in advance for your suggestions on this one. --Tim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently your autocomplete source is an array of names. But you want to populate the FirstName, LastName and Email of the selected option. So first, we need to change the source data from a simple array of names to an array of object's where each of these objects will have a FirstName, LastName and Email property.

```
@{
   var db=new MyDb();
   var userList = db.Users.SqlQuery("SELECT * from Users")
                          .Select(f => new { FirstName = f.FirstName, 
                                             LastName = f.LastName, 
                                             Email = f.Email,  
                                             value = f.FirstName+" "+ f.LastName}).ToList();

}
```

Assuming your Users table has `FirstName`,`LastName` and `Email` fields.

Now use this array of objects as the source and in the select event, get the selected item (the object) and read the `FirstName`,`LastName` & `Email` property values and set to the input fields.

```
@section scripts
{
    <script>

        $(function () {
           var userArray = @Html.Raw(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(userList));

           $("#fullname").autocomplete({
                source: userArray,
                select: function( event, ui ) {                       
                    $("#firstName").val(ui.item.FirstName);
                    $("#lastName").val(ui.item.LastName);
                    $("#email").val(ui.item.Email);
                }
           });
        });

    </script>
}
```

Comment: working on it now. Quick question what reference do I need to add for MyDb to work?
         `MyDb();`

Comment: Replace that MyDb with your DbContext class. I see you already have a `db1` object being used in the code in the question. You can use that.

Comment: Okay, I'm using class WebMatrix.Data.Database. so I changed the firs two lines to...
     `var db = new Database();
      var userList = db.Query("SELECT * from Users")`
Now it doesn't like 'new' in 'new Database()`. Error is : They type WebMatrix.Data.Database has no constructors defined.

Comment: As i mentioned earlier, you already have a `db1` object which you successfully used for getting the names. Use the same. The point, is you need to query the db to get data. So ignore the first line and use `db1` in second line

Comment: Okay, I see, basically for WebMatrix.Data.Database it would be...
     `'var db = Database.Open("myDatabase");
       var userList = db.Query("SELECT * from Users")`